# Error converting datatype nvarchar to geographic

Tags: ios, .net, xcode, web-services, ios8

I am calling .net webservice in that two paramenter(LAT ,LONG) are of geographic data type, when I am sending float value to these parameter it is giving me error Error converting datatype navarchar to geographicdatatype,How to solve this problem,Bellow is my code ,Thank you...

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             "<NI_TDR_QUESTION_ANSWER_DEPT xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                             "<StrEntityId>%@</StrEntityId>\n"
                             "<StrDeptId>%@</StrDeptId>\n"
                             "<StrStage>%@</StrStage>\n"
                             "<StrInwardNo>%@</StrInwardNo>\n"
                             "<StrMode>%@</StrMode>\n"
                             "</NI_TDR_QUESTION_ANSWER_DEPT>\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n",StrEntityId,StrDeptId,stageSelected,StrInwardNo,StrMode];
    NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"My URL"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/NI_TDR_QUESTION_ANSWER_DEPT" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init] ;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}
```

Comment: What values are you posting for the lat/long?  If you're in control of the (presumably) SQL Server, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874690/convert-nvarchar-to-geography-data-type-in-mssql) to see if it helps.

Comment: I am sending user's current location lat long